# Tensorflow: ImportError: DLL load failed: Cannot find module

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, importerror

When using tensorflow I get this error messages:

```
C:\Users\Marie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe C:/Users/Marie/Documents/emma&marie/mic/deepvoxnet/demo/demo_rthn.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in
 <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation
  File "C:\Users\Marie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Marie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>

    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\Marie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <mo
dule>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\Marie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <modul
e>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Marie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in
 <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in
 <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Marie/Documents/emma&marie/mic/deepvoxnet/demo/demo_rthn.py", line 9, in <module>
    import keras
  File "C:\Users\Marie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. '
ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It seems like the module py_wrap cannot be found. It's a relativly common problem and I found lot's of solutions online, but not a single one seems to work... I'm using the 64-bit version of python and tried lot's of things to solve this problem; downgrading tensorflow (which isn't an option since the other package, keras, needs tensorflow 2.2), reinstalling seaborn and tensorflow and practically every other solution offered here. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using Tensorflow 1 with the highest Keras version.

Follow Keras announcement on [their GitHub](https://github.com/keras-team/keras). Try to downgrade Keras's version to 2.2.5 or lower for Tensorflow 1 and 2.4.0 for Tensorflow 2.

However, if you want to use Tensorflow 2, they recommend using Keras in Tensorflow which is updated frequently (Check there Github: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/keras)

Comment: I downgraded keras to 2.2.5, the last error message is gone now, but the importerrors are still there

Comment: Also I don't get why I seem to be using tensorflow 1? I specified the version while installing and chose 2.3.1

Comment: Because I used to meet that bug before, at that time, my problem is because of the conflict between Tensorflow 1 and Keras. With your problem, could you try [this solution](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749) (galocen's answer)?

Comment: Downgrading tensorflow to 2.0 and installing visual C++ worked!

Comment: @M19rie Great, but I recommend you convert your code to use `tf.keras` instead of Keras repo, it will auto adapt with all Tensorflow version

Comment: That sounds like a better plan, how do I do this?

Comment: I am not too familiar with Tensorflow, but I think you just need to replace all `import keras` to `import tf.keras as keras` is fine.